# Use in clause with HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate HibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate and i want to use find method where i need to achieve the IN operator behavior.

```
getHibernateTemplate().find(query, value);
```

My query is,

```
String queryString = "from " + APP_DET+ " as model where model.id = ? ";
```

and my value is a array of string i am passing.

But i am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String;`

**How to achieve it in clause with HibernateTemplate?**

Answer (score 0):

I Hope the following query will help to sort your problem

```
Query q = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSession().createQuery("select distinct ci.customer " +
             "from CustomerInvoice ci " +
              "where ci.id in (:idsParam) ");
q.setParameter("idsParam", ids);
```